# Why won't any faces show up in the UV Image Editor?

Tags: uv

When I unwrap the character I designed, I get only a few faces visible in the UV image editor, although all the faces are selected in the 3d viewport in edit mode.

Those faces are probably the one I added to "close" the character's head (for some reason I had a hole that I closed adding faces one by one and then checked to remove doubles). Maybe it's a coincidence.

And there is more: If I use 'circle select' (<kbd>C</kbd> + left-click) over "empties" area in the UV image editor (not in island mode), I can see that faces get activated in the 3d viewport (edit mode)! Of course, I have restarted Blender to see if the problem persists and it does.

All this weird behavior happens before I create an image. Once I create a new image or use an existing one as a UV, the meshes in the UV Image editor don't show up at all!

When I do all this process with the monkey figure I have no problem.

Could you have a look to my blend file and tell me what's wrong?

[image: model and UVs in blender]

Blender 2.7.4 Mac OS X 10.10.3

My blend file: http://ge.tt/6CiWL8H2/v/0?c

Comment: @Chebhou Good point, retracted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 'UV Local View' turned on in the image editor. Go to the image editor and then View> UV Local View to turn it off:

[image]

I'm don't fully understand this feature but it seems to be *mostly* used for Blender Internal and not Cycles. There is a small discussion about it here:

https://developer.blender.org/T43042

Comment: Thank you Ray ! You have pointed out the solution. Now all my mesh appears in the UVimage Editor. But as soon as I create a New image, the mesh gets invisible again. After struggling to find out if and where I screwed up something, I simply copied my mesh Object mode and pasted it in a new Blender document: all the problems were gone. So maybe there is a problem in the animation or elsewhere.

Comment: @user3339083 I updated my answer with a better solution.

Comment: Uh oh. OK. "playing" with this option and with the chosen Rendering Engine solved the problem for me. The matter is too complex for my level of knowledge to have an opinion but that allows me to go on with my exercise.  Thank you very much @Ray

Comment: @user3339083 If this solved your problem you can 'accept' my answer by clicking on the check mark next to my answer. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work